# Python script does not exit after function run

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a following program that simply reads what buttons are pressed using keyboard and in case user hits Escape button, the script should stop working. The problem is that it does not do it - it stops printing buttons but does not end its operation. I tried adding `sys.exit()` function but without success.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

```
from __future__ import print_function

from inputs import get_key
from inputs import DeviceManager

def main():
    devices = DeviceManager()
    dictionaries = devices.codes
    qt = False
    while qt == False:
        events = get_key()
        for event in events:
            if (event.code in dictionaries["Key"].values() and event.code != "KEY_ESC" and event.state == 1):
                print(event.code, event.state)
            elif (event.code in dictionaries["Key"].values() and event.code == "KEY_ESC" and event.state == 1):
                qt = True
                break
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please provide a *minimal, complete, verifiable* example of the problem you're having. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm breaking for loop and after qt is set to True I exit while loop

Comment: @JacobKrall isn't it verifiable and complete? You could simply run this script.

Comment: @Michał, the `sys.exit()` must work.

Comment: @Michal: I am getting `raise UnpluggedError("No keyboard found.")`

Comment: Try printing the events and put a print statement before the break

Comment: Trivial, but you can just write `while not qt:`.

Comment: @Harvey I tried. It seems that after plugging Esc I'm after `main()` call in last line

Comment: **How** are you running this?

Comment: @Harvey in command prompt

Comment: If I get rid of all the `inputs`-specific stuff, by using `input()` instead, it works fine. So I think there may be something going on with the `inputs` library that is preventing your program from quitting. I can't get `inputs` to do anything on my VM to test it for you.

Comment: @JacobKrall try using this to install `inputs` library: `git clone https://github.com/zeth/inputs.git
cd inputs
python setup.py install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments it was package-connected issue. In this case the proper solution to problem was using `try` statement:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from inputs import get_key
from inputs import DeviceManager

def main():
    devices = DeviceManager()
    dictionaries = devices.codes
    qt = False
    try:
        while True:
            events = get_key()
            for event in events:
                if (event.code in dictionaries["Key"].values() and event.state == 1):
                    print(event.code, event.state)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score -3):

There are 2 loops in the code, while and for. You are breaking only the for loop. You should break the while loop too.

Comment: I break the while loop by setting qt to True

Comment: Sorry, noticed that a bit late.
@Michał are you sure it enters in the elif condition when pressing ESC? You can print something to check it.

Comment: Yes, I checked it using print functions and it also seems I'm quitting `main()` function call